# Python Weather API Call Issue

Tags: python, api, http, openweathermap

I am currently learning python and reached the end of a section in my teachings so I thought I would try building a few basic projects with what I have learned so far.

I found this file on git and thought I would recreate it and modify it a bit to allow user input so that they can tailor their own city/location

However, when I run the script I get an error. Please see the code below and the error under that. I didn't know if should put the entire error here or just the last lines so I thought I'd err on the safe side and put all of it. Apologies if it's really long and obnoxious.

```
import urllib
import json

previous_weather_file = "weather_log.txt"
previous_weather = ""

try:
    log = open(previous_weather_file, "r")
    previous_weather = log.read()
    log.close()
except:
    print "No previous data"

city_name = raw_input("What is the city name you would like to check the weather for? ")

f = urllib.urlopen("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city_name}")
weather = f.read()

log = open(previous_weather_file, "w")
log.write(weather)
log.close()

weather_json = json.load(weather)
#print weather
#print weather_json['weather']
curr_temp = float(weather_json['main']['temp']) - 273.13
print "Temperature is %.2f degrees C" % (curr_temp)

if (not previous_weather == ""):
    previous_weather_json = json.load(previous_weather)
    prev_temp = float(previous_weather_json['main']['temp']) - 273.13
    temp_diff = curr_temp - prev_temp

    if not (temp_diff == 0.0):
        print "Temperature has changed by: %.2f degrees C" % (temp_diff)


#error message
Serxhios-MBP:Projects SerxhioZefi$ python weather_get.py
What is the city name you would like to check the weather for? London
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather_get.py", line 16, in <module>
    f = urllib.urlopen("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city_name}")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 469, in open_file
    return self.open_local_file(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 483, in open_local_file
    raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city_name}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Change line 16 to this (you are missing the http  or https for the API)

`f = urllib.urlopen("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city_name}")`

Next you will run into `('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x104827a70>)` but that is another question, having to do with the openweathermap API. I would check their docs for the API usage. Probably you will need to include an authentication key with your requests.

I recommend the `requests` module for this type of work in python, mainly because it is enjoyable to use and simplifies many tasks:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/